# Pages: Fit two A5 page on on a single A4 page in landscape mode

Tags: macos, pages, iwork

I want to print the same content twice on a page and then cut the page into two parts. Basically I want to start with an A4 page in portrait mode, and want to end up with (approximately) two A5 in landscape.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way using Pages and Preview

- Print your page from Pages into a PDF (Open in Preview works as well)
- Open PDF in Preview
- Select "Print"

  [image]
- Switch "Copies per Page" to 2

  [image]